# Running a python script in a Gsheet button

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, rest, google-sheets

I want to use Gsheets to track accounts and group membership in a proprietary 3rd-party application. Right now I have a python script running on a server that checks the sheet for accounts and membership parameters and it works great. It will read the sheet and check the 3rd-party app and make sure they always match with the sheet being the source of truth.

However, I'm not really a Gsheet master. Recently I found that I can create buttons in Gsheets that will run JS code. I'm also not a JS master, however.

I actually have two questions. The first one I think the answer is yes. Can I hit outside resources like REST endpoints from these buttons?

If I am right and that can work. The second question is, can I have a JS script inside a button run a python script that I contain in the Gsheet somehow?

The reason is that this would make the entire process contained in the Gsheet for much easier distribution and adoption as it eliminates the need for ancillary resources to run the Python code.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If "JS" you are thinking is Google Apps Script, is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app When your server can be accessed from outside, I think that you can access to it using UrlFetchApp when a button on the Spreadsheet is clicked. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry, JS = JavaScript

Comment: But that helps a lot!